# Not able to see my lock screen activity over the default lock screen of the device - In Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-service, android-6.0-marshmallow, lockscreen

This issue is only happened in Marshmallow. Please anyone help me. My lock screen activity always displayed behind the default lock screen of the device.

I'm really blocked here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't try to cover the user's lock screen; have them disable it.

Comment: @ Epicality.. I'm new in android. I can't understand, can you explain ?